# Sitecore User Group - Budapest #2

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

The next Hungarian Sitecore User Group has been announced! There will be two topics:

- Glass Mapper Deep Dive - Attila Horváth (@POSSIBLE)
- SXA basics - Imre Németh (@ALLWIN Informatika)

Free discussions, pizza, drink and beer after the presentations.

**When (UTC):** Wednesday, May 31, 2017 5:00 PM

**Where:** POSSIBLE CEE Budapest, Bocskai út 134-146., Budapest

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/239721104/)**

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on May 21 at 17:00